# When Lichess analyzes a game, how deep does it analysis?

Tags: analysis, stockfish, lichess

In reference to the request computer analysis feature, how how deep is Stockfish analyzing, such as looking 12 moves ahead?

Answer (score 2):

It tells you at the top right.

[image]

The first number (19) tells you the depth it has analyzed to (19 ply = 9.5 moves). Note that because of engine heuristics, it doesn't exhaustively search for every single move 9.5 deep. The second number (23) tells you the max depth to which the engine is searching for. After the bar fills up, there is an optional feature that lets you increase the depth beyond 23 if you want to explore a specific position further.

Comment: @BCLC I think the original poster was referring to the location on the overall screen.  If true, then some may interpret your edit as causing harm since it is not misleading (though I understand you are only referring to the clipped image).

Comment: @SecretAgentMan yeah, you're right. I'm deleting my comment.

Comment: This is for in-browser client-side analysis though; when you "request computer analysis" (as OP states in their question) you request a server-side analysis. I don't think the depth used is going to be the same. At least because in one the numbers change as time progresses and in the other they don't.